# KO templates are not loading in Magento 2.1 application

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have an application which is running in cluster environment(2 nodes). Application is working properly in individual nodes but when I try to access it from common url none of the knockout templates are working.

**=> Error (knockout.js) :**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function
> (){return getTemplate() }" Message: thisXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: thisXXXXXXXXXXXXX is not defined